# How do I write a Qt regular expression to highlight strings starting and ending with non-word characters?

Tags: c++, regex, qt

Windows 7 SP1
MSVS 2010
Qt 4.8.4

I want to highlight any string (not word) that begins with 1 or more hyphens and/or ends with 1 or more hyphens. The string potentially includes Unicode, so I need to work with character sets.

For instance, these should be highlighted (but not the surrounding whitespace):

```
-word --word -&#$$ --&#$$ 
word- word-- &a$$- &a$$--
-word- --word-- -&a$$- --&a$$-- 
-word-word- --word--word--
```

Embedded hyphen strings with no outer hyphens should not be highlighted:

```
word-word word--word &#$$-&#$$ &#$$--&#$$
```

Hyphen strings should not be highlighted:

```
------- ---- -- ----
```

This:

```
1. QRegExp("-+[\\S]+|[\\S]+-+")
```

selects everything I want to highlight (without highlighting surrounding whitespace) but also selects what I do not want to highlight: hyphen strings and the first part of embedded hyphen strings (underlined):

```
word-word
-----
```

I believe this would not select hyphen strings:

```
2. QRegExp("-+[\\S]-[-]]+|[\\S-[-]]+-+")
```

but I don't know if Qt supports character class subtraction; this expression caused nothing to be selected.

So, my thinking is to create separate rules to subsequently unhighlight these strings.

This selects hyphen strings (which I then unhighlight):

```
3. QRegExp("[\\s-+(?=\\s)|\\s-+$|^-+(?=\\s)|^-+$"")
```

I am stuck on how to handle the embedded hyphen strings. I thought lookbehind assertions would help but they are unsupported.

**My questions:** a) Is there an easy way to select the first part of the embedded hyphen strings so I can unhighlight without selecting anything else (no other side effects)? or b) best of all worlds, is there a better way to do this in expression 1. to achieve all my objectives without unhighlighting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `QRegExp("-+[\\S]+|[\\S]+-+")` use `QRegExp("-+[^-\\s]+-+")` if you want to match one or more `-` followed by at least one non-space non-hyphen character followed by one or more `-`.

`\S` matches any non-space character including hyphen which makes hyphen-only sequences valid as `---` has a hyphen to match first `-+`, a hyphen to match `\S+` and another hyphen to match last `-+`.

Comment: Thank you so much for leading me closer to a solution! I see where I was missing the idea. This selected everything without selecting hyphen strings: `QRegExp("-+[^-\\s]+|[^-\\s]+-+|-+[^-\\s]+-+")`. However, I'm still selecting the 1st half of embedded hyphen strings (<word->word where <> indicates selection). So I lookahead to see if there is a space after (say) "word-" to get `"-+[^-\\s]+|[^-\\s]+-+(?=\\s)|-+[^-\\s]+-+"`. But that then selects the 2nd half (word<-word>). And I can't do a lookbehind assertion to confirm if there is a leading space.

Comment: Due to the lack of lookbehind, I was able to solve the problem with a two-rule process, one regexp to highlight: `"-+[^-\\s]+|[^-\\s]+-+|-+[^-\\s]+-+"` and then a subsequent regex rule to unhighlight the 1st half of embedded hyphens (plus leading spaces): `"\\s[^-\\s]+-+(?=[^-\\s])|^[^-\\s]+-+(?=[^-\\s])"`. Not elegant but does the trick. You helped me get over the hump by suggesting `[^-\\s]` and hence will mark this answered. If you have any other ideas how to make it a tad simpler would more than welcome it. Thanks!